# How to keep sshd service running all the time and set permanent FQDN hostname in CentOS7?

Tags: centos, ssh, vmware, sshd, hostname

I have installed CentOS7 in VMWare Workstation 12 player and I'm trying to use key-based SSH authentication. I have completed the process of passwordless SSH and it works fine but I have to start the SSHD service every time I open VMWare as it refuses to connect to port 22, which is the default and I haven't changed it.

The hostname is `osboxes` and the FQDN is `osboxes.local.com`. For some reason I also need to set hostname as `osboxes.local.com` all the time manually even if there is entry in /etc/hosts file.

Please suggest how to keep SSHD service running all the time and set permanent FQDN hostname in CentOS7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CentOS 7, to start a daemon on boot, one must run the command:

```
sudo systemctl enable daemon.service
```

In your case, you must run:

```
sudo systemctl enable sshd.service
```

For Fully Qualified Domain Name, you should add the following line to /etc/hosts in your host (not virtual machine) according to the ip address of the virtual machine:

```
192.168.*.* osboxes osboxes.local.com
```

After that, you can login just with:

```
ssh user@osboxes
```

Also, if one ever wishes to stop a daemon starting on the boot:

```
sudo systemctl disable daemon.service
```

is the command to run. And,

```
sudo systemctl start daemon.service
sudo systemctl stop daemon.service
sudo systemctl status daemon.service
```

are the commands to start, stop and view status of a service.

Last but not least,

```
sudo systemctl list-unit-files
```

shows what services are set to enabled/disabled on boot.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the hostname, put `osboxes.local.com` in /etc/hostname.  That will set the default hostname when the system boots.  (This is different from previous versions of CentOS, which defined the hostname in /etc/sysconfig/network.)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I edited /etc/hostname to make entry osboxes.local.com but manually I used to set FQDN by command "hostname osboxes.local.com". When i made entry in /etc/sysconfig/network it worked for me. Now after command "hostname" I get "osboxes.local.com" i.e. FQDN